# How to simplify conditionals in generic methods?

Tags: c#, generics

I've got a generic method `public void DoAThing<T>(T inputData)`.

Inside the method I need to take specific actions based on what the actual type of T is:

```
if (typeof(T) == int)
{
  // Handle integer input.
}
else if (typeof(T) == string)
{
  // Do something else.
}
else
{
  // Default action.
}
```

How do I keep that if/else statement from growing to be arbitrarily large as I come up with the actions for more types?  Replacing with a `switch` statement looks better syntactically, but has the same underlying problem: I have to add more and more cases.

Intuitively I understand that the switching has to be done at some point, I'm just looking for a more elegant way of doing it.

EDIT: The answers I'm getting aren't quite what I'm looking for, but that may be because I'm on the wrong path.  I realized that my original question was off, and that may be part of the problem.

The method I'm working with is really along the lines of:

`public T void ReturnAThing<T>(string thingName)`

As such, the reason I'm switching on T is because the method needs to do some different processing to get the return value.  In this case, what's more valid: using a generic method with a if/else for each expected type, or just having a series of methods for each valid return type (`ReturnAString`, `ReturnAnInt`, etc.)?

Comment: `Intuitively I understand that the switching has to be done at some point` No, actually, you're doing something *very wrong* if you're switching on the type at all.  If you want to do 3 different things for three different type arguments *have three different overloads*, and have no `switch`.  Generic methods should be generic; your method isn't actually generic.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps (emphasis on perhaps) what you want is something like this. (Eventually the bottom of this long answer explains why you maybe shouldn't do this. But it's good to experiment.)

```
public abstract class DoesSomething<T>
{
    public abstract void DoSomething(T input);
}
```

Now you can write individual classes that override this for specific types:

```
public class DoesSomethingWithAString : DoesSomething<string>
{
    public override void DoSomething(string input)
    {
        // Do whatever
    }
}
```

As was mentioned in a comment, something has gone wrong if you're inspecting something to see what type it is. One of the benefits of type safety is that you only need to know the declared type of an object. Even if the actual instance is something that inherits from that declared type, you don't need to know that. If the parameter says it's a `Foo` then it's a `Foo` and that's all you need to know.

If we have to inspect objects to determine their type then everything might as well just be an `object`, like this:

```
public class DoesSomething
{
    public void DoSomething(object input)
    {
        if(input is string)
        {
            // Do something
        }

        if(input is Foo)
        {
            // Do something
        }
    }
}
```

Generics make sense when the generic class doesn't "care" what the specific type is, like `List<T>`. It's going to hold instances of `T` regardless of what `T` is. Or you might put a constraint on it like:

```
public class MyFooHandler<TFoo> where TFoo:Foo
```

That ensures that the generic type is `Foo` or inherits from `Foo`. But in that case the methods should only "care" that it's a `Foo`. If you find yourself inspecting it to see what kind of `Foo` it is, then again, something has gone wrong.

If you have a class that might be operating on an `int` or might be operating on a `string`, a good question is, why does it need to be one class or one method, since it might be doing two entirely different things? Maybe there should be two classes. Maybe there should be one class with multiple methods. Maybe you only need a `string` method and your ints should be converted to strings before calling the method.

Sometimes we get lured into these problems because we're trying to figure out a way to make one class do lots of different things. That happens a lot when we're experimenting with generics. But very often the answer is that if we're doing two different things we should have two classes.

Even in the example above where two classes inherit from `DoesSomething<T>`, it's good to ask, what is the benefit of having those classes inherit from one base class? Very often there's no benefit at all and it just makes trouble later. It's best to start off writing individual classes that each do one small thing or a few closely related small things.

Answer (score 0):

You should be doing

```
public void DoAThing(int inputData)

public void DoAThing(string inputData)
```

Answer (score 0):

By having single generic method you are allowing the caller to expect any type of return value from it, but can you handle that in your method?

This example shows that you can easily break your method contract of being able to handle any return type:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public <T> T returnAThing(String input){
    if (input.equals("a") ) return (T) new Integer(1);
    else if (input.equals("b") ) return (T)"ABC";
    else return null;
}    

@Test
public void test(){
  Integer result1 = returnAThing("a"); //ok result is 1
  Integer result2 = returnAThing("b"); //fails      
}
```

I think you only have two choices here:

1) Have your method to take Class instance so that you can know what return type the caller is expecting from you. F

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public <T> T returnAThing(Class<T> type, String input){
    if ( input.equals("a") && type.equals(Integer.class) ) return (T) new Integer(1);
    else if (input.equals("b") && type.equals(String.class) ) return (T)"ABC";
    else return null;
}    

@Test
public void test(){
  Integer result = returnAThing(Integer.class, "a");  //ok result is 1      
  result = returnAThing(Integer.class, "b"); //ok result is null
}
```

2) Have separate methods for each return type.

---

Which approach is better for you? It depends. If you are dealing with handful of different return types then use separate method approach.